# Expression Engine: Database Query Not Executing As Expected

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I've setup an EE template with PHP enabled and set the PHP Parsing Stage as Input.  I would expect the following code to update the database correctly, but nothing happens:

```
<?php
    $ids= "{last_segment}";
    $userId = "{member_id}";

    $sql = "UPDATE table SET column = '" . $ids . "' WHERE member_id = '" . $userId . "'";

    $this->EE->db->query($sql);
?>
```

If I echo my query it looks correct, and in fact if I run it in PHPMyAdmin it works fine.  Is there something I'm missing?  Do I need to modify the PHP Parsing Stage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to move this question to the EE SE site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may just need parentheses after "EE":

```
$this->ee()->db->query($sql);
```

Also, I'm not sure if you need `$this`...

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html